# Ajax отправка данных на сервер

Tags: javascript, ajax

Можно ли отправить дополнительные данные на сервер в ajax в блоке success, когда изначально действие произошло успешно?

Answer (score 1):

Это пример на angularJS:

```
$http.post('/path0', {data0: Data0}).success(function (resp) {
    //Что-то важное 0
    $http.post('/path1', {data1: Data1}).success(function (resp) {
        //Что-то важное 1 при success
    });
});
```

Суть такова: вложить AJAX-запрос в success AJAX-запроса.